# how to convert the old Menu or Setting button so Android apps to the new or most common button in Barr Menu?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbaractivity

Who can leave a link in the video comment window explaining how to convert the old Menu or Setting button so Android apps to the new or most common button in Barr Menu.
It is as in the picture below.
Thank you in advance for your help.

[click here to see more detail one picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xjfy.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design a `menu` XML as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_star"
        android:title="Star"
        app:showAsAction="always">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_save"
        android:title="Save"
        app:showAsAction="never">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_color"
        android:title="Color"
        app:showAsAction="never">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_about"
        android:title="About"
        app:showAsAction="never">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:title="Share"
        app:showAsAction="never">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_clear"
        android:title="Clear"
        app:showAsAction="never">
    </item>
</menu>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: yes i'm doing this, is didn't working, i'm create my barr menu xml and certified to the same Class.Java inside the same old menu, but any barr menu is showing.
this's my first time ever with this case of barr menu, i can give you the source code to try with please ?

Comment: Post your activity code..I will try to solve as soon as possible

Comment: sorry for delay, of then yesterday that i try to post three Class Activity, but is not working with me i'm a beginner in this website,  this's the link of my source code complete  you can try one it with freedom, this my email too : mesnaouitrv@gmail.com